# How can I print the output of each line in an .ml file

Tags: visual-studio-code, ocaml, development-environment

I have an .ml file and I want to be able to run it line-by-line as if I was typing it in the top-level ocaml interpreter

The problem is, if I simply type "ocaml file.ml" in the terminal, I don't get the output from the REPL, and I can't debug and compile it, since it contains the `#use` directive.

I've tried using several different extensions for Visual Code, but none of them worked for me.

Is there anything I can do to simply be able to run the file and get the output from the ocaml REPL?

Thanks.

Comment: what about : `ocaml < file.ml` ?

Comment: @PierreG.I've tried this and it actually gives the same result as ocaml file.ml in terms of the REPL output (prints some extra stuff too). Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used VS Code (if you are referring it as 'Visual Code'), but [SLIME](https://github.com/slime/slime) in emacs or its [Vim version](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) of it is probably what you want.

Based on that, I tried searching for an VS Code extension that does works like SLIME: [SendToREPL](https://github.com/nvbn/sendToREPL).
 (Disclaimer: the author claims it works for Python, Node, and reply (not sure what it is though), but I am quite confident that it will work for OCaml REPL/UTop.)